# How to copy the raw request of a test step in SOAP UI?

Tags: soap, soapui

I am having a test suite and I am firing many web-service calls in that.
To frame the web-service request, I am using the Test Suite properties using property transfer.

For example like this `${#TestSuite#INSTANCE_ID}`, how do I copy the entire request with all the values replaced in request after it is fired?

Comment: Use XPath! If you want a more detailed answer post sample Response, sample expected Request.

Comment: I just wanted to capture the entrire request that was fired. I found it in the RAW tab after changing the preferences. I added the answer on how to set that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual request which was fired will be present in the Raw tab of SOAP UI. I have disabled this in the preferences, that was why I was not able to see that.

To see the actual request, change the following settings the SOAP UI Preferences

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! was really useful!